# Intellij reformat code adds empty string repeatedly to wrapped string ending in variable

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using intellij to format my code and have "Ensure right margin not exceeded" checked in Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java with default "Right margin (columns)" set to 120. Most things are working nicely but I've run into a reformat issue that is never satisfied with the result and continually modifies the code.

This is the method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return " time: " + this.time + " date: " + this.date + " fooo: " + this.fooo + " bar: " + this.bar + " bazzz: " + this.bazzz;
}
```

After one reformat:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return " time: " + this.time + " date: " + this.date + " fooo: " + this.fooo + " bar: " + this.bar + " bazzz: " 
            + "" + this.bazzz;
}
```

After two:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return " time: " + this.time + " date: " + this.date + " fooo: " + this.fooo + " bar: " + this.bar + " bazzz: " 
            + "" + "" + this.bazzz;
}
```

etc.

One thing that stops this madness is if I set Settings > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces > Binary expressions to "Wrap if long". But I don't want to wrap binary expression generally.

How can I fix my settings so that intellij reformats long strings ending in variables without getting into a loop?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample file and your code style settings (File | Export Settings).

Comment: Submitted https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173785